# Sign extension in assembly IA32

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sign-extension

I'm new to assembly and I'm using IA32 architecture.
I'm trying code a `.s` function that produces the following operation: C + A - D + B

- A is an 8-bit variable
- B is a 16-bit variable
- C and D are both 32-bit variables

The function should return a 64-bit value that must be printed in C and I can't figure this out.

I am trying this and it works for the tests of positive numbers, but when I'm working with negative numbers it doesn't work and I can't figure out the reason.

My function `sum_and_subtract.s`:

```
.section .data

.global A
.global B
.global C
.global D

.section .text
.global sum_and_subtract

# short sum_and_subtract(void)

sum_and_subtract:

#prologue 
    pushl %ebp 
    movl %esp, %ebp
    
    pushl %ebx
    
#body of the function

    movl $0, %eax # clear eax   
    movl C, %eax
    movl $0, %ecx
    movb A, %cl
    
    addl %ecx, %eax
    movl $0, %edx
    movl D, %edx
    subl %edx, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movw B, %bx
    addl %ebx, %eax
        
    movl $0, %edx
    adcl $0, %edx
    
    cdq
#epilogue

fim:

    popl %ebx
    
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

An correct example is:

- A = 0, B = 1, C = 0, D = 0; Expected = 1 -> Result = 1 and It works for this example

The error appears when:

- A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 1; Expected = -1 -> Result = 256

After seeing your comments I forgot to write my main code where I print my long long result.

main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sum_and_subtract.h"   

char A = 0;
short B = 0;
long C = 0;
long D = 1;

int main(void) {
    
    printf("A = %d\n", A);
    printf("B = %hd\n", B);
    printf("C = %ld\n", C);
    printf("D = %ld\n", D);

    long long result = sum_and_subtract();
    
    printf("Result = %lld\n", result);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Here it is.

I have this other file `sum_and_subtract.h`

```
long long sum_and_subtract(void);
```

Comment: The code is not correct, but it should still work for the test case you showed. You are likely printing the value wrong, as `-1` is `255` when printed as unsigned byte. Even so, you should not get `256` though.

Comment: can you explain what `print` means. How function should return 64 bit value and what print in C means

Comment: @Jester return value is 64 bits so -1 wil be 0xffffffffffffffff which is much more than 255 :)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?  This is missing the actual definition and initialization of the variables `A,B,C,D`, as well as the code that calls `sum_and_subtract` and outputs the result.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I know, but if it's printed wrong as just an unsigned byte, it will be shown as `255`.

Comment: @Jester I don't see any printing there, but maybe I am blind

Comment: There is none. My point is, José did not show the code that prints it so maybe **that** is wrong. Because the code as shown does return `-1`. Or maybe it's not printed but passed to `exit()` which truncates to 8 bits typically and the shell prints stuff as unsigned.

Comment: So your variables are all signed?  And you need to widen to avoid possible overflow by widening to 64-bit *before* summing?  Or can you do a 32-bit sum and then just `cdq` like you're doing?  It's pointless to use `cdq` after using `adc` or `setc` to set EDX to 0 or 1; `cdq` overwrites that.  First figure out exactly what math on what types you want to implement.

Comment: I already edited my question. I think the main code is correct. Maybe is missing something in my `.c` code

Comment: @PeterCordes They are all signed but I really don't know the difference between signed and unsigned. The function has to return a 64-bit value. What's the better way to do it? My teacher told me to use `cdq` but I don't see a way to use it.

Comment: What is in `sum_and_subtract.h`? Assuming `extern long long sum_and_subtract();` the code prints `-1` as expected.

Comment: @Jester I edited again.

Comment: The problem is: I have the following test: A = 5000, B = -5000, C = -1 and D = 1 that should return 10000 but doesn't.

Comment: So why did you ask about a totally different test case? Also `A` is a `char` it can not be `5000`. You are not sign extending `A` or `B`.

Comment: Because that test was wrong too. But now it only doesn't work for that test and I can't figure why. How can I sign estend A or B?

Comment: Instead of `movb A, %cl` do `movsbl A, %ecx` and instead of `movw B, %bx` do `movswl B, %ebx`. You can remove the zeroing. See also the answer below.

Comment: The answer below is for 64-bit code. I'm in 32-bit code.

Comment: That is hardly relevant to the sign extension.

Comment: The same instructions work in 32-bit mode, just using `A` instead of `A(%rip)`.  It's correct if you want to do 32-bit wrapping math, and *then* sign-extend that possibly-wrapped result to 64-bit, like you were trying to do in the question.  (Except cdq aka AT&T `cltd` not x86-64 only `cltq` (aka Intel  `cdqe`))

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the C compiler:

```
doit:
        movsbl  A(%rip), %eax
        movswl  B(%rip), %edx
        addl    C(%rip), %eax
        subl    D(%rip), %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        cltq
        ret
```

```
        movsx   eax, BYTE PTR A[rip]
        movsx   edx, WORD PTR B[rip]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR C[rip]
        sub     eax, DWORD PTR D[rip]
        add     eax, edx
        cdqe
        ret
```

It "prints" `-1`

It is rather a comment so do not UV. Feel free to DV

The complete code with print: https://godbolt.org/z/3a9YMo

And with the printing code: https://godbolt.org/z/KT8YWT

Comment: That's 64-bit code.  The OP is clearly writing 32-bit code (note the `popl %ebp`), so you should use `-m32`.  Also, this doesn't avoid overflow of the 32-bit sum before you sign-extend to 64-bit.  So right idea to ask a compiler, but you didn't ask it the right thing. :P